# where to store a logged in user?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

So I'm still learning nodejs and combining it with react in a small project and I still don't know where to store a logged in user. Should I store it in localStorage? what's the safest way? I'm still knew to this authentication thing.
Any Help is appreciated

Comment: Without knowing which authentication service(s) you're using or seeing some code, we can only answer with opinions. Have an attempt at developing your solution, searching around SO for existing answers, and read about how to produce a [minimal workable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i'm using JWT authentication with ExpressJs i've already implemented the backend side of authentication i just don't know how to link it with the frontend, it's just a knowledge question. i've read alot of existing answers and watched alot of vids with everyone of them having different solution.